# 404 error nginx rewrite

Tags: regex, nginx, url-rewriting

I'm trying to redirect like this

`/(int)/(lowercase string)/(int)/(lowercase string)/(string containt everything)?querystring`

to

`/$1/$2/$3.$4`

example: `/81/file/221/zip/Filename.Zip` to `/81/file/221.zip`

because some download managers won't look at my content-disposition header now this is my config file

```
server {
    listen xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:80;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.example.com.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.example.com.log;
    server_name example.com www.example.com;
    root /path/to/root/dir;

    valid_referers none blocked example.com *.example.com;
    if ($invalid_referer) {
        return 403;
    }

    location / {
        autoindex off;
        deny all;
        location ~ "\.(zip|mkv|mp4)$" {
            allow all;
            rewrite ^/(\d+)/([a-z]+)/(\d+)/([a-z]+)/(.*)$ $1/$2/$3.$4 break;
            add_header Content-Disposition 'attachment; filename="$arg_adlfname"';
        }
    }

    error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.htm;
    error_page 403 /403.htm
    error_page 404 /404.htm
}
```

but it gives me 404 ... so what should I do ?

**AND MAYBE** !
isn't it better do set the rule with the location ? maybe rewrite isn't needed

Comment: In you example file ends with `Zip`, it doesn't match `location`'s regexp. Probably you should use case-insensitive matching

Comment: Also you've missed leading slash (`/`) in rewrite rule.

Comment: the slash did ! (the Zip was just mistype) ... thank you so much

Comment: And you could simplify rewrite a little: `rewrite ^(/\d+/[a-z]+/\d+)/([a-z]+) $1.$2 break;`